# About auto record and auto play with AVAudioPlayer&AVAudioRecorder

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

in .h file I wrote like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SCListener.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface TalkingAndSayingViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{

IBOutlet UIImageView *bkg;
IBOutlet UILabel *showVoulme;

SCListener *listener;

NSTimer *time;

BOOL listen;
NSString *audioPath;
AVAudioRecorder *recoder;
AVAudioPlayer *player;

int breakCount;

BOOL timeActive;

}
@property(nonatomic,assign)int roleIndex;
@end
```

and in the .m file I wrote this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *searchPaths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
audioPath = [[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.wav"];
[audioPath retain];

listen = YES;

NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                       nil];

NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"role%d.png",self.roleIndex];
[bkg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];

recoder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath] settings:recordSettings error:nil];
[recoder setMeteringEnabled:YES];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath] error:nil];
[player setNumberOfLoops:0];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] retain];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error: nil];

time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(CheckVolume) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:time forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
     timeActive = YES;
        listen = YES;
        NSLog(@"fihish playing, start listen");
}

-(void)CheckVolume

    {    
        Float32 peak = [[SCListener sharedListener] peakPower];
        if(timeActive)
        {
            if(listen)
            {
                [showVoulme setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",peak]];
                if(peak>0.3)
                {
                    listen = NO;
                    [recoder prepareToRecord];
                    [recoder record];
                    NSLog(@"start recording");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if(peak<0.1)
                {
                    if(breakCount >= 5)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"start play");

                        [recoder stop];

                        player.delegate = self;
                        [player prepareToPlay];
                        [player play];
                        timeActive = NO;
                        breakCount = 0;
                    }
                    else 
                        breakCount++;
                }
                else
                    breakCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [recoder stop];
    [[SCListener sharedListener] stop];

    timeActive = NO;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    timeActive = YES;

    [[SCListener sharedListener] listen];

    breakCount = 0;
}
```

Here have some problems,
first:audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying  this function didn't do at all, and this code only can run to "start play", but the sound didn't play in fact, I used to use the recorder to check the volume when it's in the recording condition, but the peakPowerForChannel:0 only returns a static value of 0.00001, I have no idea to solve this problem, anyone can help me or send me a sample code of auto record and auto play? I really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I think that **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** method isn't called because you set **player.delegate = self;** in very strange place.
Better to set delegate right after initialization of player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, already 5 years past, and I still work with iOS dev, this problem been resolved in about one month after this question ask, and I never remembered to see this answer. I had made an app like talking tom just then. And already finished it, however, useless for me.